Is there any way to successfully combine a ScrollView with drag gestures in SwiftUI?
I would have thought this was trivial to do in SwiftUI, but apparently not.
Imagine a list of Items, each with some text in, within a ScrollView or something which scrolls (VStack maybe). The list goes off the screen so the user can scroll to see the bottom.
I want to be able to re-order that list as well, by dragging Items. Let's assume a one sec delay before it lets you 'pick up' the Item, and then drag to re-order. The delay is so as not to conflict with scrolling. And the dragged item should look exactly like the non-dragged item (except maybe a shadow or outline or something)
Is this possible with SwiftUI?

Have you tried using a List (which has built-in scrolling)  and an .onMove callback?

List is way better choice then ScrollView

Try using a List with an .onMove callback on the ForEach:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var rows: [Int] = Array(1...100)
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(rows, id: \.self) { i in
                Text("Row \(i)")
            }
            .onMove { fromOffsets, toOffset in
                rows.move(fromOffsets: fromOffsets, toOffset: toOffset)
            }
        }
    }
}



Thanks, that works. But I was hoping for something flexible. That could be used on ScrollViews and VStacks and HStacks

@cannyboy I think a List is probably the only native (easy) solution. Using a ScrollView would require a custom solution. You could maybe try using a .highPriorityGesture for the DragGesture, but I'm not sure if there is any way to intercept a gesture and then let it go through to the native handler if you decide not to perform any action. You will find quite a lot of SO posts on the subject.

Thanks. Just seems weird to me that something so fundamental is (probably) impossible. We’ll have to wait till iOS 22 until we can do in SwiftUI what takes 20 lines to do in JQuery
